# Excepción producida: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' en mscorlib.dll (error por un atributo definido en byte[])

Tags: c#, windows-forms, webservice, byte

EL ERROR ES: Excepción producida: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' en mscorlib.dll.

Tengo un webservice soap java (en netbeans 8.2) que se conecta con una base de datos de oracle 21c y consumo este webservice mediante c# en un proyecto windows forms en visual studio, hice una clase en el webservice para rescatar informacion de la bd y que esta se guarde en una lista la cual llamo mediante el client en c# (referencia de servicio), hasta el momento funciona totalmente bien excepto cuando quiero rescatar el atributo foto que es de tipo byte[], antiguamente esta referencia de servicio funcionaba perfectamente en wpf pero con windows forms no me funciona el obtener el byte[] que posteriormente lo convertia a imagen.

Si alguien sabe como podría evitar este error también averigue algo de maxRequestLength aunque no se si tenga relación.

También si me recomiendan una forma de enviar y recibir o manejar fotos o tipos blob o byte[] en c#, además esa lista la cual no solo tiene el atributo de imagen, también tiene otros atributos.
PD: en la BD el atributo foto se guarda como BLOB, en el web service en el resultset le hago un getbytes()

**Metodo de listado en el web service.**
[image: lista]

**Error en el cliente/consumidor al traer una *lista* que contiene en sus atributos un atributo que es de tipo byte[]**
[image: ERROR]

Comment: No sabemos el método que lanza la excepción.

Comment: Hola actualice el post, con un catch capture en donde se produce que es en la respuesta del webservice en c# y el error es que la lista contiene un atributo en byte[] probablemente sea por lo largo o grande que debe ser, mi duda es ¿cual es la mejor manera de enviar una foto o un file desde el webservice a c#?, la foto es almacenada en blob en la bd pero le hago un getbytes y ahi se transforma en el byte[], pero c# no logra aceptar esta lista y tira el error de CommunicationException.

Comment: winform y wpf son el medio de visualizacion... el lenguaje de base es el mismo, por lo tanto, salvo que hayas cambiado otra cosa, deberia funcionar en los dos igual...

Comment: Sinceramente no sé cual sea el error antiguamente me funcionaba perfecto pero algo debe estar limitando el largo de arreglo de bytes quizas alguna actualización de visual o algo por el estilo que termina la conexion, no encontre mucha información relacionada a ella ni se como modificar ese tamaño que supongo hace referencia al buffer del atributo retornado, al final "Solucioné" el problema y extraje los bytes del blob y le realice un getEncoder y esto lo guarde en una variable tipo String, esta la envie mediante el ws a c# como string alla la transforme de base64string a imagen y funciono.

Answer (score 0):

No es la solución que esperaba pero funciona.

Cambie el atributo de tipo byte[] a string.

En el  ResultSet (rs) realice un getbytes() y luego este parametro le realice un encoder a base64 guardado en una variable string como muestro a continuación:

```
Java web service soap:
          String strimg =Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rs.getBytes("img_logo"));
          formulario.setImg_logo(strimg);
 Csharp C#:
         public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }

    private void ListarFormularios()
    {

        dtgnotfi.DataSource = ListarFormulario();

    }
    public IEnumerable<object> ListarFormulario()
    {
        List<string> lista_nula = new List<string>();

        lista_nula.Add("No se encontraron datos");
        try
        {
            wsNMA_.WS_NMAClient cliente = new wsNMA_.WS_NMAClient();
            return (from c in cliente.ListarFormularios().ToList()
                        
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = c.id,
                        imagen = Base64ToImage(c.img_logo)

                    }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


            return lista_nula;
        }
    }
    private void AgregarCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListarFormularios();
    }
```